# Expo App not updating on iOS physical device (Expo Go)

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-go

I'm trying to run my app on my phone with Expo Go but changes I make to the code are not being updated. Both my devices are on the same wifi network and Fast Refresh is enabled. When I reload the app on the Terminal, it says the bundling with my phone is complete, so it doesn't seem to be a connection error...

Any thoughts ?

Thanks!

Comment: try to clear cache with `expo r -c`

Comment: It says my JavaScript transform cache is empty but nothing changes... Not updating.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. If you're using Visual Studio Code, make sure you click on "Trust" the files you're coding on...

Comment: Where do you see that you can click on "Trust" the files?